# Counter for true values XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I need to count all ProductOwner's which have true value. In my case I have one true value, so as output I will get number 1.

Here is my XML code:

```
<ClientList>
  <Client>
    <ProductOwner>true</ProductOwner>
  </Client>
  <Client>
    <ProductOwner>false</ProductOwner>
  </Client>
</ClientList>
```

I want to get such an output XML code:

```
<ClientList>
  <Client>
    <Number>1</Number>
  </Client>
</ClientList>
```

Here is my XSL code, but it doesn't work properly:

```
<Number>
  <xsl:variable name="Number" select="substring(ProductOwner, 1, 4)" />
  <xsl:for-each select="ClientList/Client">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="(ClientList/Client/@ProductOwner)='true'">true</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</Number>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to use `count()` against an appropriate `XQuery` expression?

This should return what you need:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ClientList>
            <Client>
               <Number>
                   <xsl:value-of select="count(/ClientList/Client/ProductOwner[text()='true'])"/>
               </Number>
            </Client>
        </ClientList>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think the xpath should reflect the full path indicated the the OP, as it might be the case that `ProductOwner` appears as children of other elements besides `Client`. And it should be noted that support of XPath functions can be limited based on the XPath or XSLT interpreter that runs the given XSLT xml. (I'm probably being nitpicky on this point, but I have personally hit my head into the wall trying to figure out why something didn't work only to find out it was the interpreter, not the xml, that was the issue).

Comment: @Anthony True! You'll find a lot of answers given by me where I tell everybody *be as specific as possible!* :-D The *deep search* is something to be avoided in most cases... Well, let's say, I was just showing the principles...

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="ClientList">
        <xsl:element name="ClientList">
            <xsl:for-each select="Client">

                    <xsl:if test="child::ProductOwner='true'">
                        <client>
                    <number>
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(ProductOwner)"/>
                    </number>
                            </client>
                </xsl:if>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```